# Delete pointer memory allocation to avoid memory leak

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-memory, allocation

I would like to delete a pointer at the end of the FOR loop to avoid memory leak. However in the middle of the FOR loop, it may hit a condition `if (i > maxHour / 2) continue;` and continue back from beginning. To avoid memory leak, I was trying to do this check `if (NULL != p) delete[] p;` but the program could not compile. I am not sure what is wrong with this line `if (NULL != p) delete[] p;`

```
   int main() {

        int maxHour = 8760;
        int *p;
        for (int i = 0; i < maxHour; i++) {

            if (NULL != p) delete[] p;

            p = new int[100];

            //do some things 1

            if (i > maxHour / 2) continue;

            //do some things 2

            delete[] p;
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might want to start by initialising `p`.

Comment: C++? NULL? How about including the actual compiler error?

Comment: Yep. Deleting an uninitialized pointer is a bad, bad idea. Also a good idea to set it to NULL after the `delete[] p;` at the end of the loop to avoid a double delete when the loop loops back to the beginning.

Comment: Deleting an invalid pointer is also bad

Comment: Why are you using dynamic allocation in the first place? Just declare a local array inside the loop.

Comment: because the size of p can change

Comment: "because the size of p can change" - no, it can't.

Comment: ***because the size of p can change*** That is why in `c++` we use vectors and other containers. Although I assume the reason you are doing this is you are not permitted to use the standard library.

Comment: Not sure why everyone is down-voting you to be honest. You're new at C++ and that's fine.. It's a legit question.. Bad code, but legit question. People can suggest a better way to write it and what is wrong with it.. but instead you are down-voted to oblivion :l

Comment: Using `std::vector<int> p;` and just calling `p.resize()` within the loop would be more efficient than calling `new[]` and `delete[]` on every single iteration.

Answer (score 3):

Several problems.

First, you need to initialize `p` to `nullptr` so that the first iteration doesn't try to access and free an uninitialized pointer.

Second, after you delete the pointer at the end of the loop, you need to set it to `nullptr` so the next iteration won't try to free it again.

Finally, you need to free it after the loop, in case the last iteration hit the `continue` statement so it skips over the `delete`.

```
int main() {

    int maxHour = 8760;
    int *p = nullptr;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxHour; i++) {

        delete[] p;

        p = new int[100];

        //do some things 1

        if (i > maxHour / 2) continue;

        //do some things 2

        delete[] p;
        p = nullptr;
    }
    delete[] p;

    return 0;
}
```

You don't need `if (NULL != p)` because `delete` automatically checks for a null pointer and does nothing.

Another way to do it is to delete the pointer before continuing. However, if you have lots of different code branches that contain `continue`, this might be inconvenient to repeat.

```
int main() {

    int maxHour = 8760;
    int *p;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxHour; i++) {

        p = new int[100];

        //do some things 1

        if (i > maxHour / 2) {
            delete[] p;
            continue;
        }

        //do some things 2

        delete[] p;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why, after posting this comment: " Just declare a local array inside the loop. " are you posting this answer? One of them is redundant.

Comment: He said in a comment that the size of the array changes. I assume the hard-coded size in the question is for example purposes.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Are you the downvoter? For that reason?

Comment: This is the best answer here.. It explains everything wrong with OP's code and shows how to fix it. However, I do have one comment: It is tagged C++ and not C++11 so `nullptr` "MIGHT" not be an option.. but that can be overlooked. +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

For such a task the smart pointer `std::unique_ptr` is suitable.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct A
{
    ~A() { std::cout << "A::~A()" << std::endl; }
};

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 10;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        std::unique_ptr<A[]> p( new A[2] );

        if ( i % 2 )
        {
            std::cout << "\nContinue" << std::endl;
            continue;
        }

        std::cout << "\nIteration" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Iteration
A::~A()
A::~A()

Continue
A::~A()
A::~A()

Iteration
A::~A()
A::~A()

Continue
A::~A()
A::~A()

Iteration
A::~A()
A::~A()

Continue
A::~A()
A::~A()

Iteration
A::~A()
A::~A()

Continue
A::~A()
A::~A()

Iteration
A::~A()
A::~A()

Continue
A::~A()
A::~A()
```

As it is seen the memory is deleted correctly independent on whether there was executed the continue statement.

You can use the subscript operator with this smart pointer the same way as with arrays.

Comment: I think OP wants to preserve the previous allocation when `continue`ing.

Comment: @user4581301 I think he just declared the pointer in the outer scope though the pointer is used only in the inner scope because it is deleted in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Yeah. You're right. I'm on crack. OP nukes it either way.